# Erro ao criar arquivo PDF no Android

Tags: android, pdf

Estou com um problema para criar um PDF usando o iText no Android.
Tenho que salvar na memória interna do dispositivo,
mas esta dando erro pois não sei o caminho para salvar porque no tutorial ele salvava no `C:/temp`.

Este é o código

```
public class PdfActivity extends Activity {

    private static String file = "texto";
    private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD);
    private static Font smallBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,Font.BOLD);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf);

        try {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
            document.open();
            addTitlePage(document);
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void addTitlePage(Document document) 
        throws DocumentException{
            Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();

            //pula uma linha
            addEmptyFile(preface, 1);
            //titulo com font grande
            preface.add(new Paragraph("Documento de Teste", catFont));

            addEmptyFile(preface, 1);
            preface.add(new Paragraph("Conteudo teste do corpo, um texto simples para ser exibido como corpo do documento", smallBold));
            document.add(preface);
            document.newPage();

    }
    //metodo para pular uma linha
    private static void addEmptyFile(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
        for(int i=0; i<number; i++){
            paragraph.add(new Paragraph(""));
        }
    }           
}
```

A variável `file` é onde vai o caminho.
Uma imagem do LogCat:

[image: erro]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em qual caminho você está a salvar o arquivo PDF? em todo caso você pode estar olhando as [`Variáveis de Ambiente`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) para obter informações sobre os diretórios do sistema. Veja um exemplo, um arquivo `FooBar.pdf` será criado no diretório padrão de *documentos*.

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf);

    try 
    {
       Document document=new Document();
       File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS); 
       File pdffile = new File(path, "FooBar.pdf");
       PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdffile));
       document.open();
       document.add(new Paragraph("Foo Bar Bar Baz Baz Foo"));
       document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Consegui o que estava acontecendo era que ele não achava as classes da biblioteca mesmo exportando o jar, ai copiei o arquivo e colei na pasta libs e deu certo , seu código me ajudou muito criou o documento certinho, obrigado