# Gerar PDF com imagens no Android

Tags: android, pdf

Preciso gerar um PDF no Android com alguns campos simples e várias imagens.
Pesquisando encontrei essa questão [Erro ao criar arquivo PDF no Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16518/erro-ao-criar-arquivo-pdf-no-android)
que está me ajudando. Porém não sei como posso adicionar as imagens no PDF, no momento elas estão salvas no dispositivo e eu tenho o caminho delas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma outra biblioteca chamada PDFBox, caso não estiver conseguindo utilizar o iText.

https://pdfbox.apache.org/

> Com iText é possivel realizar um merge(combinar), então mesmo com
>   novas imagens, poderia ir adicionando conforme for surgindo.

O necessário você já tem, o caminho, caso for estático, pode utilizar diretamente ou dinamicamente caso precisar escolher.

http://developers.itextpdf.com/

Ex:

```
private void combinaImagensEmPdf(String caminhoImagens, String caminhoSaida) {
    try {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("arquivo.pdf"));
        document.open();
        File files[] = new File(caminhoImagens).listFiles();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        for (File file : files) {
            table.setWidthPercentage(100); //Altera e configura
            table.addCell(criarCelulaDeImagem(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
        document.add(table);
        document.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static PdfPCell criarCelulaDeImagem(String caminhoImagens) {
    Image img = Image.getInstance(caminhoImagens);
    return new PdfPCell(img, true);
}
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425738/merge-multiple-images-in-a-pdf-file